# MooTools - Rotating images by degrees

Tags: mootools

I need to rotate an image by x amount of degrees using MooTools. I Googled for quite a bit and found a lot of attempts, but all the examples and demos were broken. The closest I got was a Homer Simpson demo, but it repetedly throws the error "getMatrix is not defined".

My entire script is finished, I just need a way to rotate an element. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial for rotating images: http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-rotate-image-using-javascript-canvas.html.

It doesn't use mootools, as it is pure JavaScript. The code itself is compact enough that you probably wouldn't save too many lines using mootools anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. Unfortunately it does seem to require jQuery.